# Как можно написать функцию линии из символов?

Tags: python

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет рисовать "линию" символами в консоли Python, я попробовал написать список всех элементов а именно список screen
с 20 элементами, в каждом элементе по 40 символов. Это получается некое разрешение,по x - 40 символов, а по y - 20 символов

Функция отрисовки пикселя

```
# функция, изменяющая символ в списке на заданных кординатах
def px(x,y,symbol):
    # создаём кординаты,
    # а так как это список,
    # отсчёт идёт с нуля,
    # то уменьшаем х и у на 1
    xPos = int(x-1)
    yPos = int(y-1)
    
    # изменяем по кординатам символ
    screen[yPos] = screen[yPos][:xPos] + str(symbol) + screen[yPos][x:]
```

Функция отрисовки всей "картинки"

```
#функция, выводящая на экран "рисунок"
def check():
    i = 0
    #цикл выводящий все 20 элементов списка screen 
    while (i <= 19):
        print(screen[i])
        i += 1
```

Теперь нужно написать функцию линии, принимающую 5 параметров:
X1(позиция по x первой точки),
Y1(позиция по y первой точки),
X2(позиция по x второй точки),
Y2(позиция по y второй точки),
symbol(символ, которым рисовать линию)

Как написать функцию линии используя эту формулу нахождения центра:

> **round(x2-x1):2+x1**

Comment: `screen[yPos][:xPos] = symbol` Это тоже самое, нет?

Comment: splash58, наверно да, просто программирую на питоне не очень давно, ещё не совсем разбираюсь